# Make fixed contents of column not span entire page width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ATyIkFULHQoMp1pgdtAj?p=preview) to show my issue.

I have the following layout where I have a menu on the left and page contents on the right.  I'd like to fix the menu so, if the page contents result in vertical scrolling, the menu will not move.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="main-nav">
        <!--Menu here-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <!--Page contents here-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

The menu has links which I'd like to take up the width of the `col-sm-2` they are in, but when `position: fixed` is applied, it takes up the entire page width.

Comment: @Chirag That does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the .main-nav to right:0; left:0; you're making it span the entire width. If you remove these lines (you can set top:0; left:0; if you want to be safe about the menu position) it should work the way you want.

```
.main-nav {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   width:inherit;
   /*OPTIONAL with current code*/
   top:0;
   left:0;
}
```

EDIT: Setting the width of .main-nav to inherit will span it the entire width of col.-m-2

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  That fixes the issue where the menu items are taking up the entire width of the page.  How do I get them to take up the entire width of the `col-sm-2` now, though?

Comment: I'm sorry didn't realize I'd only fixed half the problem, see edit :)

Comment: I actually updated my Plunkr.  There was a `nav-menu` element (Angular2 component) that wasn't included in my original markup.  It appears to be what's preventing this from working even after the `width: inherit`.  Mind taking a look again?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you need both elements? If you move the css from .main-nav onto .nav-menu it works how you want, but the more you next the more difficult it's going to get.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Angular2, there is no `replace: true` so I will need both.

Comment: Can you move the css from .main-nav onto .nav-menu